# Which is the correct word to use: "I'll rather" or "I'd rather"?

Tags: grammar, subjunctives

I want to write a sentence to a friend indicating that instead of looking at the one thing, it's better to look at something else. Do I say, "I'd rather" or 
I'll rather" look?

Answer (score 1):

## I would rather / I'd rather

This is an example of the **subjunctive** -- something that refers to [possibilities rather than facts](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/subjunctive).

Since you are giving **your friend** advice on what to do, it may or may not be done:

> I **would rather** look at something else (if I **were** you).

Anytime the situation is **theoretical**, or **not certain**, you should use the subjunctive ("**I would rather**").

Don't forget to capitalize "I".

## I will rather / I'll rather

We discussed in the comments whether "I will rather" ("I'll rather") also exists.   [Google N-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+will+rather%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20will%20rather%3B%2Cc0) confirms that "I will rather" has almost disappeared, but it was more common before 1900.

Here are a couple of ways that "I will rather" may make sense:

> - **When I die,** I **will rather** be cremated than buried.
> - **When I go** to Italy next year, I **will rather** visit my birthplace than my uncle.
> - **When I go** to Greece next year, I **will rather** go to the islands than the mainland.

In each of these cases, the speaker is *certain*, and it is not theoretical.

The first one -- death -- is especially certain.  It may not make sense to say:

> - If I eventually die, I would rather be cremated than buried.

Feel free to use "I will rather" if you have a situation where **you are certain of the future**.

Comment: Thank you very much. is there such a thing as "I'll rather" or do we always have to say "I'd rather"

Comment: With theoretical situations we use would.

Comment: I tried to think of an example of “I will rather” when I was writing the answer, but I couldn’t think of one.    Google n-grams confirms that “I will rather” has almost disappeared, but it was very common before 1900.  I agree that it requires a *certainty* to say “I will.”

Comment: I've added to the answer an explanation of when you can use "I will rather".   Feel free to check the checkmark icon if this answer worked for you!

Comment: The reason we don't use *I will rather* is the same reason we don't use *I will maybe*.  **Will** is determinative.  *Rather* and *Maybe* are not.  Mixing the two is confusing.